# Как получить значение коллекции HashSet?

Tags: c#

Коллекция HashSet обладает такими хорошими свойствами:

> 1) Searching in `HashSet<T>` is extremely fast because the `Contains`
>   method of the `HashSet<T>` collection uses hash-based searching
>   mechanism to find elements.
>
> 2) Duplicate elements cannot be added in a `HashSet<T>`. Duplicate
>   elements, if added are internally ignored without giving an error.
>
> 3) Indexed based element access is allowed in a `HashSet<T>`.

метод `Contains` возвращает значение `Boolean`, как же возможно получить значение, допустим JAPAN из кода представленного ниже, только без использования `foreach` ?

```
HashSet<string> countries = new HashSet<string> { "JAPAN", "USA", "AUSTRALIA", "CANADA", "CHINA", "RUSSIA", "FRANCE" };
```

Answer (score 4):

Ваш вопрос в целом бессмыслен поскольку для строк операция "получить" значение из хэшсета практически бесполезна. У вас уже есть строка "JAPAN"? Вы хотите получить из хэшстета какую-то особую строку "JAPAN"? Я вас разочарую - она будет точно такой же как и ваша (а возможно той же самой благодаря интернированию).  Собственно, какой тогда смысл ее "получать"?

Как вы сами отметили, в этом классе имеется метод Contains, он указывает, содержится ли искомое значение в хэшсете, этого вполне достаточно. При необходимости вы можете использовать  цикл, или обертку вроде linq, если не хотите пользоваться циклом (но скорее всего цикл будет задействован внутри). Например что-то такое:

```
string japan = country.FirstOrDefault(x =>  x == "JAPAN");
```

Смысл может иметь получение значений по каким-то другим условиям, отличным от равенства. например, все значения длиной от 7 символов:

```
var greaterThanSeven = country.Where(x =>  x.Length > 7);
```

Либо же получение значений может иметь смысл для каких-то сложных типов данных, где фильтрацию можно выполнять по отдельным полям. Например:

```
        var country = new HashSet<Foo>
        {
            new Foo { id = 1, name = "JAPAN" },
            new Foo { id = 2, name = "USA" },
            new Foo { id = 3, name = "AUSTRALIA" },
            new Foo { id = 4, name = "CANADA" },
            new Foo { id = 5, name = "CHINA" },
            new Foo { id = 6, name = "RUSSIA" },
            new Foo { id = 7, name = "FRANCE" },
        };

        var foo = country.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "JAPAN");
```

Comment: О, точно. Вы поняли, что хотел ТС.

Comment: Не могу найти вас в чате. Проголосуйте за синонимы, пожалуйста: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B/synonyms

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос. Только пример неудачный. Давайте рассмотрим класс:

```
class Class1
{
    private Int32 _value;

    public Int32 Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Class1 c1 = obj as Class1;

        if (c1 == null)
            return false;

        return c1._value == _value;
    }
}
```

Создадим пару объектов и добавим их в HashSet:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1() { Value = 1 };
Class1 c2 = new Class1() { Value = 2 };

HashSet<Class1> set = new HashSet<Class1>{c1, c2};
```

Далее мы получаем ключ, по которому нужно получить объект из HashSet:

```
Class1 key1 = new Class1() { Value = 2 };
```

Суть в том, что по значению `c1` и `key1` одинаковы, но это два разных объекта:

```
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(key1)); //true
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(c2, key1)); // false
```

И HashSet покажет, что он содержит подобный объект:

```
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(key1)); //true
```

Объект подобный, но не тот.

Чтобы получить тот объект придется сделать перебор:

```
Class1 result = set.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Equals(key1));
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(c2, result)); // true
```

Comment: MaLS: c2 и key1 по значению одинаковы

Comment: @Vladimir Это как посмотреть. Некоторые под значением переменной типа класса подразумевают значение ссылки на объект.

Answer (score 1):

Получить конкретное значение из HashSet невозможно.

Comment: Зашифрованного? о_О

Comment: `HashSet` работает совсем не так, как вы написали.

Comment: HashSet хранит и хэши и зашифрованные значения. Т.е. если вы в него добавите два объекта с одинаковым HashCode - то в нем реально будет лежать два разных объекта. Упоминание Hash в имени класса только намекает на то, что для ускорения операций используется хэширование, но никак не говорит о подверженности класса коллизиям хэш-функции.

Comment: Согласен, мое пояснение не совсем верно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите получить *тот самый* элемент, который вы положили с `HashSet<T>`. Конкретно с `HashSet<T>` за O(1) это невозможно, но легко смоделировать при помощи `Dictionary<T, T>`, если размещать **один и тот же элемент** в качестве ключа и значения.

```
T GetItemEqualTo(T pattern)
{
    T result;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(pattern, out result))
        return result;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Вам понадобится generic constraint `where T : class`.

(Это не скомпилируется для value-типа `T`, но в этом случае понятие *того самого* экземпляра лишено смысла.)

Comment: конкретное значение, допустим JAPAN из кода представленного выше

Answer (score 0):

Для получения значения по ключу надо использовать `Dictionary`.

Различные нужны именно для проверки наличия, и, возможно, сортировки. Получить какой-либо объект из них можно только в цикле foreach и аналогичными способами.

Comment: почему? в Dictionary я могу получить значение так:  `myValue = myDictionary[key]`

Comment: @Vladimir, вот именно, в словаре можешь, а в сете не можешь. Признаки, что ошибся классом: нужен выбор по ключу - меняй сет на словарь, заметил, что все значения в словаре true - меняй его на сет.

Comment: Для чего вообще нужна эта коллекция HashSet????

Comment: @Vladimir, для того, чтобы значть, был уже такой объект или нет. Например, с её помощью можно исключить дубликаты из коллекции.

Comment: @Vladimir, вопрос непонятен.